# Python how to count colums in a csv open using DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I tried to count the columns of a csv open with DictReader using this code

```
with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as myfile2:

    reader = csv.DictReader(myfile2)
    first_row = next(reader)
    num_cols = len(first_row)
```

and it works, but the problem is when i tried to iterate using

for row in reader:
   ...

it starts in the second row, not the first row after the header. I suppose, after reading the documentation, than the problem is using next(reader), but i couldn't find another way to count columns.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [csv.DictReader.fieldnames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to take the count of the columns:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    num_cols = len(reader.fieldnames)
    for row in reader:...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
with open(file_name, "r") as myfile2:
    reader = csv.DictReader(myfile2)
    num_col = len(reader.fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        whatever
```

As a side note, `len(first_row)` is not for the faint of heart. For dictionaries you probably want to use `len(first_row.keys())`, even if your original code works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the `reader` - it is an iterator, which keeps giving the next iteration value.

When you can `next()`, it returns the first line. If called again it would return the second. And if after calling `next()` you have a for loop, it won't start at the top - it would start where you left off after `next()` calls.

So, you either:

- don't call `next()`, or
- you re-define the `reader` again before calling it in a loop, or
- pre-compute the output of the reader (only do it if small csv files).

I hope that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

[csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) accepts an `fieldnames` argument, which is a sequence of column names, or headings if you prefer.  The docs say:

> If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file [...] will be used as the fieldnames

In the code in the question, `fieldnames` is omitted, so the first row is automatically consumed by the reader, to get the column names.  Calling `next(reader)` consumes the second row, so iterating over `reader` starts at the third row.

```
>> import csv, io
>>> data = """A,B,C
... 1,2,3
... 4,5,6
... """
>>>
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data))
>>> print(next(reader))
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
>>> for row in reader:print(row)
... 
{'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'}
```

As kederrac points out in their answer, you use the value of `reader.fieldnames` to get the length of the  rows - it will be populated automatically by the `DictReader`:

```
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data))
>>> print(reader.fieldnames)
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> for row in reader:print(row)
... 
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
{'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'}
```