# Python3: how to count columns in an external file

Tags: python, csv, import, text-files

I am trying to count the number of columns in external files.  Here is an example of a file, `data.dat`. Please note that it is not a CSV file.  The whitespace is made up of spaces.  Each file may have a different number of spaces between the columns.

```
Data                    Z-2              C+2
m_[a/b]                -155555.0        -133333.0
n_[a/b]                -188800.0        -133333.0
o_[a/b*Y]              -13.5            -17.95
p1_[cal/(a*c)]         -0.01947          0.27
p2_[a/b]               -700.2           -200.44
p3_(a*Y)/(b*c)          5.2966           6.0000
p4_[(a*Y)/b]           -22222.0         -99999.0
q1_[b/(b*Y)]            9.0             -6.3206
q2_[c]                 -25220.0         -171917.0
r_[a/b]                 1760.0           559140
s                       4.0             -4.0
```

I experimented with `split(" ")` but could not figure out how to get it to recognize multiple whitespaces; it counted each whitespace as a separate column.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178098/python-how-to-count-colums-in-a-csv-open-using-dictreader) seems promising but my attempt only counts the first column.  It may seem silly to attempt a CSV method to deal with a non-CSV file.  Maybe this is where my problems are coming from.  However, I have used CSV methods before to deal with text files.

For example, I import my data:

```
 with open(data) as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     n_cols = len(reader.fieldnames)
```

When I use this, only the first column is recognized.  The code is too long to post but I know this is happening because when manually enter `n_cols = 3`, I do get the results I expect.

It does work if I use commas to delimit the columns, but I can't do that (I need to use whitespace).

Does anyone know an alternative method that deals with arbitrary whitespace and non-CSV files?  Thank you for any advice.

Comment: @shelter, sorry about that!  I hate it when other people do that but realized you were right that I had written a novel.  It wasn't a great question.  I can find out if I can reinstate it if you like.  I figured out a sort-of solution but don't really understand why it works.

Comment: @shelter, yes, I do tend to include a lot of information.  It's because some responders can be harsh.  I like to show I've made an effort.  I only need to use Awk every year or so, so tend to forget what I've learned.  I'm slowly making progress and can handle simple tasks but I usually have problems that don't seem to have beginner-level solutions.  My work is very broad and I do often need to go beyond my abilities in certain areas.  Anyway, thank you for your effort.  Don't worry about spending any more of your time!  Appreciate it.

Comment: Deleting irrelevant comments from `awk` code version, now replaced with python. Glad you got a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are alternative methods:

### Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', delim_whitespace=True)
```

### NumPy

```
arr = np.loadtxt('data.dat', dtype='str')
# or 
arr = np.genfromtxt('data.dat',dtype='str')
```

### Python's `csv`

If you want to use the python's `csv` library, you can normalize the whitespaces first before reading it, eg:

```
import re
with open('data.dat') as csvfile:
    content = csvfile.read().strip()
    normalized_content = re.sub(r' +', r' ', content)
    reader = csv.reader(normalized_content.split('\n'), delimiter=' ')
```

Comment: thank you very much.  I tried some pandas methods but was missing delim_whitespace.